Linear Diophantine Equation with some change of variables
I have a linear Diophantine Equation in integers $x,y,z$ of the form:
$$ax+b(y+1)+c(z+1)=d$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are integer parameters.
Putting $Y=y+1$ and $Z=z+1$ , I can show the solvability of the resulting equation by the standard methods.
My question : Is my approach valid for this case ? What are the changes between the two equations.

Why would it not be valid?  Alternatively, you could rewrite as $ax+by+cz=D$ where $D=d-b-c$.  Not sure what you mean by "solve" though.  Clearly there is a two dimensional family of solutions (at least in general).

What was your Solution ? When you got $(x,Y,Z)$ , then you can get $(x,y,z=x,Y-1,Z-1)$ easily.

What standard methods?

@user2661923: Calcualting the $gcd$ and conclud the existence of solutions.

Please demonstrate by finding all solutions of $$3X + 2Y + 5Z = 50 ~: ~X,Y,Z \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$$  The only approach that I know of is to let (for example) $~\displaystyle c = \left\lfloor \frac{50}{3} \right\rfloor,~$ let $~X~$ range through $~{0,1,\cdots,c},~$ and then for each value of $~X,~$ find all satisfying $~(Y,Z).~$ Do you know of any other approach?

@user2661923: your gcd is 1 divide 50, then the equation has solutions.  You can use the formula in this page https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Bachet-B%C3%A9zout to find positive solutions.

or by insepection by using the Frobenius Number: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html

It depends on what you mean by solve the equation.  If you mean prove the existence of at least one solution, without identifying the solution, then yes the linked page works.  Alternatively, if you accept the more conventional interpretation of being required to identify all solutions, then the linked page is no help.

@user2661923: I means proving the existence of solutions.

Perhaps you could edit your posted question to clarify what you intend by solving the equation.

There is a typo in my [Previous Comment][https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4976335/linear-diophantine-equation-with-some-change-of-variables#comment10657009_4976335] where I "obviously" wanted to write $(x,y,z)=(x,Y−1,Z−1)$ , naturally.
